# Браузер выводит тег как текст

Tags: html

Есть табличка в которой вместо стилизованного вывода происходит вывод всего тега таким как он написан в исходнике.

Вот скриншот консоли браузера того что делается в DOM

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

а вот так выглядит вывод в браузер

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять как такое может быть ?!

Из дополнительной информации могу только добавить что таблица генерируется стандартным виджетом yii1. А текст вместе с SPAN тегом попадает в нее из SQL запроса.

Comment: Просто веб-инспектор не экранирует текст при его отображении в DOM, в исходном html-коде этот span наверно экранирован

Comment: Я думаю что проблема в том, что этот тег не понимается браузером. Возможно он не правильно применен или устарел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первую очередь рекомендую проверить код, генерирующий этот фрагмент HTML. Бывают ошибки, когда, например, латинская "a" заменена на русскую "а". Тогда тег, конечно же, не распознается.

Также, как уже рекомендовали в комменатрии, стоит посмотреть код не веб-инспектором, другим средством - возможно, данный тег каким-либо образом экранирован.

Кстати, ещё на правах гипотезы - если используется JavaScript / JQuery, то данный фрагмент может помещаться на страницу не через innerHTML, а через innerText, что может также, гипотетически, привести к подобному поведению.

Comment: да. оказалось что веб инспекторе нет видимости того что символы на самом деле экранированы. php их экранировал.